# How to check if a WordPress post has child and siblings?

Tags: wordpress, parent, siblings

I need to hide a piece of code from showing up in certain pages. These pages are all child and siblings of the parent page with ID 8194.

To hide the code inside the child page I'm using `if ( get_post_field( 'post_parent' ) != 8194 )`, but the issue is that there are several sibling pages and that code isn't working on them, it only works in the child page.

This is my page hierarchy:

```
Parent page 1
- Child page 1
-- Sibling page 1
-- Sibling page 2
...
-- Sibling page 10
```

How can I hide the code in the sibling pages as well?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want to find the top-most parent.

For this I would use `get_post_ancestors()` which retrieves the IDs for the ancestors of a post (and returns a parents array): https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_ancestors/

Try something like this:

```
global $post;
$parents = get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
// Get the 'top most' parent page ID, or return 0 if there is no parent:
$top_parent_id = ($parents) ? $parents[count($parents)-1]: 0;

if ($top_parent_id != 8194) {
...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I need to find the top most parent. Your code is working but it is also hiding my piece of code in the parent. I just need to hide it in the child and sibling posts.

Comment: Oh, that is because the suggested code returns the current post ID when there are no parents, try using this modified version (I've edited my answer).

Comment: I've run into a small issue. Is there a way to exclude a single child page from your code using a given ID? I tried adding the exclusion inside the conditional, but it is not working, I guess the other part of the code is bypassing it.

Comment: When you say 'exclude' you meant that you want to show or hide the code on that page id?

Comment: Yes, I need to show the code in that particular page. Right now I'm hiding the code on all the other child and sibling pages.

Comment: I've posted a separate answer for this - i hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

** UPDATED CODE FOR OP'S SECOND QUESTION FROM THE COMMENTS: **

```
global $post;

// Don't show the code by default:
$show_code = false;

// This is an array of post ids where you want to show the code regardless of the parents id
$always_show_the_code_on_these_posts = array(111, 222, 333);

// Check if current post id is on the list:
if ( in_array($post->ID, $always_show_the_code_on_these_posts) ) {
    $show_code = true;
} else {
    // ...and only if it's not on the list run the previous test:
    $parents = get_post_ancestors($post->ID);

    // Get the 'top most' parent page ID, or return 0 if there is no parent:
    $top_parent_id = ($parents) ? $parents[count($parents)-1]: 0;

    if ($top_parent_id != 8194) {
        $show_code = true;
    }
}

if ($show_code) {   
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wp_get_post_parent_id()` function to check if the current page is a parent or a child by comparing it with the `get_the_ID()` function. `is_page()` here, is just a redundancy.

```
<?php
/**
* wp_get_post_parent_id
* Returns the ID of the post’s parent.
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_parent_id/
*
* get_the_ID
* Retrieve the ID of the current item in the WordPress Loop.
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_ID/
*/
if( is_page() && wp_get_post_parent_id( get_the_ID() ) ):
  //child
  echo 'This is THE Child, Grogu';
else:
  //parent
  echo 'This is THE Mandalorian, Mando';
endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'm getting the same results. I can hide my code on child pages but not on siblings since I don't know how to check that. Maybe adding the ID of the child? But I also have a lot of those so I'm trying to automate this.